# Filtering Nothing and unpack Just

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble with this program.

```
filterJust :: [Maybe a] -> [a]

filterJust [] = []
filterJust x = map fromJust (filter (isJust) x)
```

but ghci keeps reporting this

[image: but ghci keeps reporting this]

EDIT:

I don't want to use any additional module so i made this:

```
filterJust :: [Maybe a] -> [a]

filterJust x = map unpack (filter (Nothing /=) x)

unpack (Just a) = a
```

and i get this message

[image: and i get this message]

and i dont understand why. I should be able to use Eq functions without importing anthing right?

Comment: `fromJust` and `inJust` are not in the Prelude, but live in Data.Maybe. You need to start your module with a line like `import Data.Maybe (fromJust, isJust)` (which imports `fromJust` and `inJust` into global scope) or `import Data.Maybe` (which imports everything from `Data.Maybe` into global scope). Also, please just copy the text of the errors of one compilation round to the question, rather than taking a screenshot of six compilation rounds with the same errors.

Comment: Why do you need `filterJust [] = []`?

Comment: thanks a lot Rhymoid. Im stupid and tought it actually is in Prelude

Comment: The Prelude is quite messy, so it's not dumb to think `fromJust` and `isJust` are part of it.

Comment: please cut-and-paste your error messages as text, not pictures.

Answer (score 34):

You don't need to write `filterJust` function. It is already in `base` and it is called [`catMaybes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes):

Also, you can see better way to define this function:

```
catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
catMaybes ls = [x | Just x <- ls]
```

So all you need to do is just add `import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)` into your module.

Here this function is using the "MonadFail sugar" design pattern for lists. You can read more about it and other patterns in the following blog post:

- https://kowainik.github.io/posts/haskell-mini-patterns#monadfail-sugar

Comment: Also [`mapMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:mapMaybe) can be useful

Answer (score 3):

- `/=` can only be used on values of a type that implements `Eq` (`(/=) :: (Eq a) -> a -> a -> Bool`).
- `Maybe a` supports `Eq` only if `a` does (there's an `instance (Eq a) => Eq (Maybe a)`).
- Your type signature says that `filterJust` works for all types `a`, even those that don't implement `Eq`: `[Maybe a] -> [a]`

Therefore `filterJust` can't use `/=`.

Comment: How would you correct `filterJust` so that it could use `/=`?